# How do you get a mapbox's marker?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to add markers to a map using the

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer({
                                    type: 'Feature',
                                    geometry: {
                                        type: 'Point',
                                        coordinates: [ll[0], ll[1]]
                                    },
                                    properties: {
                                        title: d[i].screen_name,
                                        media: d[i].media_url,
                                        id: d[i].source_id,
                                        text: d[i].text,
                                        userId: d[i].user_id,
                                       'marker-color': '#000',
                                        'marker-symbol': 'star-stroked'
                                    }
                                }).addTo(map);
```

method but how do I from there access that marker? map.getLayerAt(0) or something?

It doesn't; display on the map for some reason..

Comment: How are you loading your marker(s) into the featureLayer? Where is the data coming from? GeoJSON?

Comment: @adaam I am creating the data on the fly from a json set that isn't GeoJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocked this up quickly based on an example on the Mapbox site:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-zr0njcqy');

map.featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
    var markers = [];
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) { markers.push(marker); });
    cycle(markers);
});

function cycle(markers) {
    var i = 0;
    function run() {
        if (++i > markers.length - 1) i = 0;
        var marker = markers[i];
        console.log(marker.getLatLng());
    }
    run();
}
```

You can use the cycle() function to do stuff with each individual marker - if you look in the console you'll see that you can know access the marker's internal properties like latLng etc. I don't know what you want to do with each marker, so if you provide more information I'll be able to assist you more!